# Radio button group on server side ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, forms

I'm using a standard form rather than an ASP.Net form and posting it so my controls are not server controls.

I have a group of 3 radio buttons all with the same name (so that they group together). But when I use

```
Request.Form["input_radiogroup"]
```

I just get the value "on". How can I find out which radio button was on if they all have the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned from `Request.Form["input_radiogroup"]` will be the value of the selected radio input form element.

For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="input_radiogroup" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="input_radiogroup" value="1" />
```

The possible values will be either 0, 1 or null (if none are selected).

Comment: Thanks that was it exactly, I thought it might have been ID's but that wasn't working either.